# Python - How to create a Class from a package without the full import path?

Tags: python, import, package

Imagine a package with those folder and file

```
package_name
../folder_name_one
../../folder_name_two
../../../file.py 

class FarAway: # in file.py
    pass
```

Is it possible, (with **init**.py or some sys.path or something else) to import class `FarAway` simply by importing `package_name`

```
import package_name
fa = FarAway()
```

I know I can do

```
from package_name.folder_name_one.folder_name_two.file import Faraway
fa = FarAway()
```

but I would like to "setup" the package so I have access to all the subfolder, so I can organize my files but I don't want to be forced to

- always do a import with full path
- to all put in one big file.

Thanks!
If it is not possible, I would like to know...

Answer (score 0):

Simply put an `__init__.py` file in the `package_name` folder that has the contents:

```
from package_name.folder_name_one.folder_name_two.file import Faraway
```

It might also be

```
from folder_name_one.folder_name_two.file import Faraway
```

depending on how you call the files importing Faraway.

More info: https://docs.python.org/3/reference/import.html#regular-packages